# Get scrollTop, scrollLeft etc. from element with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, django, selenium, webdriver

In a Python/Django test for an element, that is scrolled via `scrollTop`, I want to get the value of `scrollTop`.

In JavaScript I get this value via

```
element.scrollTop
```

In Python I tried the following:

```
element.get_attribute('scrollTop')
```

This gave me `None`. 
How can I get `scrollTop` in Selenium?

Comment: That `scrollTop` - would that be the _JQuery_ method?

Comment: I don't think so, as @JimEvans pointed out it's a property

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollTop` of an element is not an attribute, but a JavaScript property. You'll need to use the `execute_script` method to retro this property value. The code would look something like this:

```
# WARNING! Code translated from other languages from memory.
# Exact Python syntax may be incorrect, and need adjustment.
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollTop;", element)
```

Comment: Note that a `WebElement` has to be passed to the `execute_script`method. Passing the result from `element(by.css(...))` directly causes CallStackSize error, that's why one has to use `element(by.css(...)).getWebElement()`